# A simple Vertex Buffer Object (C++) that doesnt render

Tags: object, opengl, buffer, vbo, vertex

Im trying to use VBOs to render just a normal 2d textured square onto an FBO. Immediate mode functions work flawlessly but not this VBO. GL_TEXTURE_2D is already enabled for the code. What is wrong with it?

```
unsigned int VBOid = 0;
unsigned int Iid = 0;

float *geometry;
unsigned int *indices;

int num_geometry = 1;
int num_vertices = 4;
int num_indices = num_geometry*num_vertices;
geometry = new float[num_geometry*num_vertices*4];
indices = new unsigned int[num_indices];

indices[0] = 0;
indices[1] = 1;
indices[2] = 2;
indices[3] = 3;

/* Fill geometry: 0, 1, = vertex_xy
*                2, 3 = tex_coord_uv
*/
geometry[0] = 0.0f;
geometry[1] = 0.0f;
geometry[2] = 0.0f;
geometry[3] = 0.0f;

geometry[4] = 50.0f;
geometry[5] = 0.0f;
geometry[6] = 1.0f;
geometry[7] = 0.0f;

geometry[8] = 50.0f;
geometry[9] = 50.0f;
geometry[10] = 1.0f;
geometry[11] = 1.0f;

geometry[12] = 0.0f;
geometry[13] = 50.0f;
geometry[14] = 0.0f;
geometry[15] = 1.0f;

glGenBuffers(1, &VBOid);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOid);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(geometry), geometry, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glGenBuffers(1, &Iid);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, Iid);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

//GL_TEXTURE_2D is already enabled here
//Buffers are already bound from above

glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 2); //I used 2 just to test to see if it is rendering a texture correctly. Yes, 2 does exist in my program thats why i arbitrarily used it
//glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0); I dont know what this is for and where to put it

glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
//glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0); same here I dont know what this is for or where to put it
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(GLfloat)*4, 0);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(GLfloat)*4, (float*)(sizeof(GLfloat)*2));

glDrawElements(GL_QUADS, num_indices, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indices);

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

Comment: `sizeof(geometry)` as buffer size in `glBufferData` is the first obvious error i can see. That will always return the size of your pointer `(4)`. Also, why do you set some z values to 0 and some to 1? You should really get your debugger running and verify line by line what you are sending to GL...

Comment: well those are the texture UV coordinates. The syntax is 2 UV for every xy

Comment: @user1775989 Did you actually read the first part of his comment (which is exactly your problem, as shown in my answer) or only his irrelevant second part?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your usage of `sizeof(geometry)` (and the same for `indices`) inside the `glBufferData` calls. Those variables are actually just pointers, no matter if they point to dynamically allocated arrays (which the compiler doesn't know). So you will always get the size of a pointer (4 or 8 bytes, depending on platform).

Replace `sizeof(geometry)` with `num_geometry*num_vertices*4*sizeof(float)` and `sizeof(indices)` with `num_indices*sizeof(unsigned int)`. Well, in fact you don't need any indices here at all and can just draw the whole thing with a simple

```
glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);
```

Always be aware of the differences between an actual (compile-time sized) array and a mere pointer pointing to a dynamicallly allocated array, with the result of the `sizeof` operator being *one* of those differences (and the requirement to free the memory of the latter using `delete[]` at some later point in time being another, but not less important, difference).